# How can i make flat button size as it's child size

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to make button size like it's text child size 
i will attach  example photo , and i'll attach the code that i write

this is my code :

```
        Expanded(
        child: FlatButton(
          minWidth: double.infinity,
          height: 20,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: (){},
            color: Colors.grey,
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10) ,
            ),
            child: Text(
              'SHOP' ,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ,
                fontSize: 16 ,
              ),
```

and this is the photo
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3i9q.jpg)

Comment: add a parent `SizedBox.expand`, so the hierarchy is: ``SizedBox.expand`` > `FlatButton` > `Text`

Comment: thx for ur reply 
 but i have this error when apply ur solution 

'BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
'

Comment: I think, you can use "RawMaterialButton".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
RawMaterialButton(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 4, 14, 4),
  elevation: 0,
  onPressed: () {},
  fillColor: Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
  shape: StadiumBorder(),
  child: Text(
    'SHOP',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 16,
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image: button sample]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing to me, I am not sure whether you want your button as big as the parent's child (as you stated in the title), or if you want it as big as the `Text` child (as you stated in the description of your question).

If what you want is the button to be as big as the **parent**, consider using [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) and [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) to make the button as big as the available surrounding space. You can do something like this:

```dart
  LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: constraints.maxHeight,
        width: constraints.maxWidth,
        child: FlatButton(
          ...
        )
      )
    }
  )
```

If you want the button to be as big as its **child**, I believe you don't need to worry about anything other than providing the proper `Text` widget. `FlatButton` will figure out its size accordingly.

Comment: i'm sorry about confusing u , and thanks for ur reply , i edited my question , i need to make the button shape size same as text size inside the button ,,

Answer (score 0):

```
GestureDetector{
onTap:(){},
child:Container(
child:Material(
shape:RoundRectangleBorder()
child:Center(
child:'Text')))
}
```

You can use properties of Material widget this way. If you don't provide height to container it will adjust to the child size. i.e. text size

Comment: thanks for ur reply , ur solution does not adjust child width , i need to make the height and width of button , the same as text inside ,,,

Answer (score 0):

Try this for button function:

```
Expanded(
//Modify below factor as your requirement
  flex: 1,
  child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
//Modify width,height as your requirement
      height: double.infinity,
      width:double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: Colors.blueAccent.withAlpha(30),
        ),
     child: Text('SHOP',
           style: TextStyle(
           color: Colors.blue,
           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
           fontSize: 20)),
          ),
        )),
```